# What would be a good way to attract attention in Law SE to my law-tagged questions in Space SE?

Tags: discussion

Space Exploration SE has a [law tag](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) and currently 66 questions there use it. I've asked a few of them myself. At one point we had an active user with "space lawyer" in their username answer several questions quite nicely, but that's no longer happening.

**Question:** What would be a good way (or ways) to attract the attention of some users active in this site to my law-tagged questions in Space SE?

---

Here are my tagged questions for example:

Unanswered or no having accepted answers:

- [Regulations that prevent SpaceX from saying “no” if OneWeb asked them to launch their satellites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34508/12102)
- [What are the main issues addressed by New Zealand's recent rocket legislation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21634/12102)
- [What body of regulations (if any) would apply to a cubesat with an SDR on board?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17444/12102)

Having accepted answers:

- [Might ISRO's 2018-004 launch be at least a technical violation of the Outer Space Treaty by India?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25981/12102)
- [What computer programs does ITAR say I can or can not write, or share, or use in the US?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21050/12102)
- [Do owners of reentering spacecraft notify the countries' whose airspace they are likely to violate and seek permission?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35090/12102)

---

Another user's question that triggered me to ask this meta question:

- [Who is accountable for damage caused by the debris field of a successful ASAT test](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35098/12102)

Comment: need help with proper tagging

Answer (score 3):

Discussing this on meta should help, and perhaps in the chatroom as well. That said, short of migrating the questions to Law.SE or hitting the HNQ list, the user bases may be such that there isn't considerable overlap.

Comment: Thanks! It's the probable lack of considerable overlap that motivates my question here about how to overcome it. Long term there may be some way to address cross-disciplinary questions in a future SE, but right now I guess these are the main tools available.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to ask the mods of Law.SE to make a feed in the sidebar chat that adds posts from Space.SE tagged [law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law). The chat is only so active but this might give a reason for people to visit more often.

Comment: Interesting thought. Is that something that happens automatically? Do you know if something like that has ever been implemented between one SE site and another in the past?